# Reg ex - awk - grep from getline result

Tags: command-line, grep, awk, regex

I have a expr in awk, but I can't grep the result

```
echo 34100 | awk '{expr $1 / 33.7 | getline result;}' 
-> sh: 1: 1009.89: not found
```

the calculation is ok but I need to have the `1009.89` and not this `sh: 1: 1009.89: not found`. What is the right command therefore?

Comment: What are you grepping? How can we help you parse something if you don't show us what you're trying to parse? Please [edit] your question and show us the input you are passing to your `awk` script and the output you would like to see from it. Also, explain what the awk is supposed to be doing. It looks like you're trying to use shell commands in an awk script.

Comment: ... sorry, but is solved

Comment: The fact that it is solved does not mean you don't need to clarify the question. This is not a help desk.

Comment: @jacob - It is now edited and is marked as solved.  What could I do more? Thanks for this lesson .

Comment: If you're not interested in an answer to this question (e. g. for the sake of future readers) please delete this question. Otherwise it will be deleted automatically due to being on hold after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit confused by your command. If you just want to divide and grep that output,

```
| awk '{ print $1 / 33.7 }' | grep ...
```

Will work.

If you're trying to do something else (like only output parts of rows based on this calculation, you'd be better off doing the whole thing inside `awk`:

```
| awk '($1 / 33.7 > 2) { print $4 }'
```